# Windows CE: roadmap for full screen .net application with video chat capabilities

Tags: .net, architecture, video, windows-ce

I have to develop application that should launch as soon as windows CE is started up. User should see the "OS-starting" screen and then the application form without observing desktop & other apps icons. Application should provide some functions + function to start video chat via the local network (no Internet is required).

Please, give me the roadmap to develop such a thing for Windows CE on .net CF platform: architecture, technologies, additional software you'd personally choose & some pitfalls I shall take care about for implementation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So you're asking us to architect the entire thing for you here on SO?  This is a huge request, as building embedded devices is not a simple task (no matter what the marketing people might say).

You're going to need:

- a platform that you can "adjust" so you can not show the desktop.
- to remove explorer.exe, or at least the reference to it in HKLM\Init.
- to write a C/C++ launcher and have it [launch from HKLM\Init](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx).
- to write an app to provide "some functions."
- to write (or buy) a library or app that provides your "video chat"
- hardware with a camera, or a camera with a CE driver (and CE hardware that supports the interface)
- hardware/enclosure that meets your requirements
- Experience or time to get that experience working with CE (the fact you're asking the question indicates to me you don't have a lot of this)
- Hardware that can handle the graphics and network load of what you want to do
- Loads of practice with P/Invoking

I can't really comment on architecture since I have no idea what your requirements, existing assets or experience might be.  I'd use the OpenNETCF.IoC framework for dealing with the UI, IoC and event aggregation issues.  You'll likely need to create custom controls.

Comment: I'd put an emphasize on the HW with camera support. Each individual camera needs to be tested with its WinCE driver. Havnig model 1.X work does not mean that the driver will work correctly for model 1.(X+1). If you need to have this system for along time, HW changes might kill you...

Comment: Thank you so much, @ctacke, I'm definetelly has no experience with WinCE right now so any help and suggestions are extremely appreciated!